# make the display order based on another table value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables `request` and `status_tracker`. I want to list the row in top which has only one entry in status tracker.

I have the query in `$user=DB::table('request')->select('request.*)->get();`

I want to add the order based on `status_tracker` table. If `request_id` has count '2' in `status_tracker` table I want to display in top of the table

```
 $user=DB::table('request')->select('request.*)(order may happened here)->get();
```

if ID 19,11,15 has 2 count in `status_tracker` it should display first and rest of them will display below as 19,11,15,18,17,16,14,13,12,10.

Is it possible by order the row based on another table  field count in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'withCount' which will add a column named `{relation}_count` and orderBy with that, so try something like this:.

```
$user = App\Request::withCount('status_tracker')
           ->orderBy('status_tracker_count', 'desc')
           ->get();
```

You can read more about this on [official Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

***Note:*** Your model relationship should be well established in order for this to work, so make sure you have specified the relations between both tables :D